# Java sub project with dependency from super project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, project

I am developing a Java robotics application in a proprietary Eclipse environment.

Some of my packages shall be used in other applications, so I moved them into a separate (sub) project. The code in this sub project relies on the robotics libraries. However, the separate applications are running on different versions of this library. I now want some sweet way of providing this shared sub project to my colleagues without having the robotics library as a hard dependency to leave it to them using the respective version.

In an application project this shared sub project is included as a dependency as well as the library. So in C++ I could just use typenames since the linking would be provided later - **but how to do this in Java?**

Little drawing to make the setup clearer:
[Overview of project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Vk9.png)

*Things to note:*

- I cannot use Maven, the build process is included in a synchronization workflow with the robot system through the modified Eclipse.
- It can be considered that all code in the subproject is available in both versions of the robotics library.
- Classes in that sub project must be inheriting from library classes, so they have to be imported directly.
- The contents of the robotics library cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sweet way to do this like you would like. The only way to accomplish this in Eclipse without using Maven would be to have the unique dependency versions included in the Eclipse project's classpath. Java doesn't care about what version of the libraries are included on the classpath, as long as all of the required classes, methods, etc. exist in the library class files. This is just a bad practice because if you are developing with one version of a library, it would be hard to always guarantee that the code you are writing is also compatible with the library that your colleague is using.

The best way, without Maven, would be to include all the required libraries in a lib directory of your project so that all developers are using the same ones.

Comment: OK, thanks, I just had the hope somebody might have a beautiful solution :-) For now I just ended up putting the library in a subfolder that is excluded in the git repository but required in the project file. Thus every user is required to put these file in there himself and we can deal with different versions without messing up the other people work.